# Group policy software installation Upgrade vs Replace

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2008-r2, deployment, msi

I select upgrade in gpo software install to upgrade an existing package. I am not replacing the package.

Will the old package *and* the upgrade package be installed on new computers joining the domain?

Comment: It might not be obvious, but you are actually replacing the package. Check the application logs on the system you are deploying the 'upgrade' to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the new package will get installed on computers added to the domain.

Comment: A simple answer to a simple question. Got to like it.

Comment: Sorry, my answer was a little brief wasn't it :) - To be honest, I don't know of any links to support my claim, but I know the answer to this question as I've spent many years packaging and deploying software using MSI files via GPOs